# How to integrate SonarLint with Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint-intellij

I am trying to run Solar Lint with Intellij, when I configure the SonarQube server in the plug-in and "Test Connection"

I keep getting the following error message:

> The following plugins do not meet the required minimum versions,
>   please upgrade them: java (installed: 3.7, minimum: 3.8)

I do not fully understand what this means and I would really appreciate any help on this.

P.S. I cannot upgrade the Java Plugin on the sonar server if that is the only solution to this problem because I have no access to the server administration capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

The message is clear enough and you understood it well: when you want to connect SonarLint to a SonarQube server, there are some constraints on the language plugins that are installed on this server.

In your case, the version of the SonarQube Java plugin is 3.7 whereas only versions above 3.8 are supported in the connected mode.

If you don't have administration permissions, there's nothing you can do about it. You have to stay in the default mode - i.e. no connection to the server, until the SonarQube instance gets updated.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I do not have administrative rights and I am for now going to run it in default mode. Thanks.